# How do I say thank for forgiveness for my mistake?

Tags: formality

I would like to thank for someone's tolerance because of forgiveness for my mistake. is it possible to say "Thank you for your tolerance"?

Comment: This is OK, but "thank you for your understanding" is more commonly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a perfectly reasonable statement. It would be taken well by a stranger or a boss.